# Trying to get a Yes // No prompt to work. Will not take in a response

Tags: java, arrays

```
void searchForPopulationChange()
  {
     String goAgain;
     String response;
     int input;
     int searchCount = 0;
     boolean found = false;
     boolean search = false; 


     while(search == false)
     {

        System.out.println ("Enter the Number for Population Change to be found: ");
        input = scan.nextInt();


        for (searchCount = 0; searchCount < populationChange.length; searchCount++)
        {
           if (populationChange[searchCount] == input)
           {
              System.out.print(""+countyNames[searchCount]+" County / City with a population of "+populationChange[searchCount]+" individuals\n");
              found = true;
           } 

        }

        if (found == false) {
           System.out.println("No records found!");
        }


        System.out.println("\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n\tDo you want to enter data for another Course? Type Yes or No: "); 
        response = scan.nextLine(); //the response is already recognized - thus ends or restarts the program      

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
        {
           search = false;
        }

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));
        {
           search = true;
        }      



     }


  }
```

}
hello!
This is my program so far,
Basically,
When the while loop comes to an end,
I need for it to prompt the user if he wishes to execute the program again.
Yes or no?
I get the prompt to print
however, the scan function does not work.
Any advice?

Comment: I'd recommend removing all the cruft from your code that's unrelated to the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about TYPO

Comment: it might help to link to all code in pastebin . but seems like Mark has answer anyway , below

Answer (score 7):

Remove the semicolons from

```
if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

and

```
if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));
```

Comment: nice catch, subtle ;-)

Comment: lol, here's an advantage of putting opening bracket next to the closing parenthesis :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of your other problem (beside semicolon after `if`s) will be fact that you are using `nextLine` after `nextInt` which wont consume new line mark, so first `nextLine` will return empty string. To get rid of it try

```
input = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();//to consume new line mark
```

or

```
input = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```